# How to remove extra border on "page' broken" table?

Tags: html, css

I have a long table, multi-page table thats breaks between pages. The table has borders and border-collapse as collapse. But on printable preview - there is some extra border. How can I remove it?

Here is working example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxLjvK

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
      <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
      <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
      <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
      <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more rows here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: The border takes 'line-width || line-style || color'. The sequence specified is incorrect `border: solid 1px;`

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I use latest Chrome Mac os. And see that extra border.

Comment: I can't even see the issue in the codepen provided.

Comment: @randomSoul may be you can view it here https://rmjwx1o2kq.codesandbox.io/ (as whole printable page). I see exactly as my screenshot.

Comment: No. The print page is showing correctly. It seems like there is no any issue with your code.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue, Please share your Print CSS for more clarifications. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui i have no css in this example, html only.

Comment: Hi @Molfar I am facing the exact same issue. Did you find a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Real problem is `border-collapse: collapse`, so i remove it and also move all **inline CSS**. Working fine at my end, please try it i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.print-table {
 border: 0;
}

.print-table tr {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}                 

.print-table tr td {
 border-style: solid;
}

.print-table tr td + td {
 border-left: 0;
}

.print-table tr td div {
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table class="print-table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
      <td class="border"><div>text</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the style for .border class?

Comment: Nothing! No styling need for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your style `border-collapse: collapse`
instead use 
`cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"`
so your table look like

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  ---

</table>
```

also change style of some `tds` to avoid double bordering

**preview**
https://2ooon0o550.codesandbox.io/

**code** 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/2ooon0o550

Comment: http://snpy.in/Wvf2nD when bordering individual td's, and without border-collapse...

Comment: you need to add cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" and style tds accordingly.
see this
https://2ooon0o550.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this style to make the page break  correctly:

```html
<html>
<head>


<style>
    @media print
  

      {
 body {
    padding-bottom: 10mm;
  }
      table {page-break-after:auto;border-collapse: collapse;}
      tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
      td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
      div   { page-break-inside:avoid; }
      thead { display:table-header-group }
      tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    }

   </style>
</head>

<body>
   

     <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
   <tr >
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
          <td class="border" style="border: solid 1px;"><div style="height: 150px;">text</div></td>
        </tr>
  
        <!-- more rows here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Molfar could you try it now.

Comment: @Molfar try to change the browser.

Comment: how did you get this result (on you recent screenshot)? could you share html for that? isn't there any double border?

Comment: @Molfar https://drive.google.com/open?id=1biuOUpR9xm4UQi8OjoiVlnenN81N0mYe

Comment: My browser Chrome Mac os 73.0.3683.86 generates following result https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UzGrd_oyFx8acbJs4A0mzShO4Tlt9yBS/view?usp=sharing - as you see, there is that line I'm talking about... Anyway, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Molfar try to change the printer.